# Simplifying Conditional Operators

Tags: java

My friend wrote this code for an assignment in his programming class:

```
public class test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      double x = 0.9;
      double y = 0.1;
      boolean truth = x < 1 && x > 0 && y < 1 && y > 0;
      System.out.println(truth);
   }
}
```

I'm wondering (for myself) if there's a way to simplify the conditional operators in this line specifically:

```
boolean truth = x < 1 && x > 0 && y < 1 && y > 0;
```

Comment: Do all those conditions need to be true or only one needs to be true?

Comment: You might be able to do something with bit operations, but whether that is considered "simpler" is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code...its a common check to see if a point is in a rectangle. You are stepping over the line from code quality into mental masturbation IMO

Comment: You could pull it into a method that returns a boolean to make the code more clear. ex. `truth = coordsWithin(1, 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: Consider the rectangle in the x-y coordinate plane with points(0,0) (0,1) (1,0), (1,1). His condition is the same as checking if the point lies within that rectangle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your only option for a one-liner is to use parenthesis. Personally, I prefer multiple statements to make things much clearer:

```
boolean isXInRange = x > 0 && x < 1;
boolean isYInRange = y > 0 && y < 1;
boolean truth = isXInRange && isYInRange;
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution, although both syntax versions are very readable to me...

Comment: I like this answer because it imparts meaning to the code. This is a good example to follow for a student/programmer-to-be.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it *might* be made clearer (opinion):

```
boolean truth = (0 < x && x < 1 && 0 < y && y < 1);
```

The flipping of the zero check makes it easy to read as `0 < x < 1`. Is that clearer? A very little bit.

The parenthesis is a style choice. Since boolean expressions are always parenthesized in `if` statements and `while` loops, I find it clearer to always parenthesize boolean *operators*.

Comment: I would argue 'clearer' means : `truth = (0 < x && x < 1) && (0 < y && y < 1)` though it isn't much more helpful

Comment: `0 < x && x < 1` is improvement but why do we need these outer parenthesis? Did you perhaps miss `) && (` in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for Java:

```
public boolean betweenExclusive(double start, double end, double val) {
    return val > start && val < end;
}
```

and then:

```
boolean truth = betweenExclusive(0, 1, x) && betweenExclusive(0, 1, y);
```

or a little bit fancier ;)

```
boolean truth = Stream.of(x, y).allMatch(x => betweenExclusive(0, 1, x));
```

Answer (score -3):

I am simply combining two answers (@Andreas and @Justin Niessner) here, so real credit goes to them.

```
boolean isXInRange = 0 < x && x < 1;
boolean isYInRange = 0 < y && y < 1;
boolean truth = isXInRange && isYInRange;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both answers are quite clear and short. Do we really need their combination?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Pshemo.  I think there is value in combining 2 things and coming up with something that improves (in one's opinion) both. That said, your feedback is appreciated and I will always consider this when answering future questions!